# Keep global variables in gulp

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I am using gulp to minify my JS files. However I am minifying some library files also.(Backbone.js).

Now I can't access global variable declared on that library files (Backbone). In console it is undefined.

I am pretty sure that I have to pass some argument in uglify of gulp (this is my guess).

But what

my gulp code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var wrap = require('gulp-wrap');
var declare = require('gulp-declare');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('minify-js', function() {
    gulp.src("libs/*.js")
        .pipe(concat('common-script.min.js'))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to figure out the cause? Does it mangle the variable names? Does it remove it as dead-code? Two things you could try: Remove `pipe(uglify())` from the chain, does it work now? What happens if you disable mangling the variable names? `uglify({mangle: false})`?

Comment: And how do you minify Backbone.js? I could imagine that this does already not export global variables because it got changed into a [`IIFE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)-type module.

Comment: Now I don't understand anything. All library files are already minified. When I load them separately (in script tag) everything works like a charm (I can access Backbone variable)......But when I combining them and loading combined file nothing works. I checked the code is same in both file (related to Backbone.js).

Comment: I am not minifying Backbone I am just combining all minified files

Comment: After you combine them, you minify (uglify) them a second time. It's difficult to figure out what's going on with this little information. Maybe you could add your files to the question? Are there any errors in the browser console? Maybe because the order of the concatenated JS-files is wrong? (i.e. file A depends on backbone.js, but gets concatenated before backbone?) Does it work when you comment out `.pipe(uglify())`?

Comment: Instead use minified version of library.